# Subtracting background from tif stacks in matlab

Tags: image, matlab, background, tiff, stack

I have a stack of tif images taken from camera and one .tif image of background. I'd like to subtract the background from each image of the stack. What happens if I use the imsubtract function? Does it subtract the background from each image, or just the first image in the stack? Sorry if this is a stupid question, I just couldn't find the answer anywhere.
Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

imsubtract subtracts eachelement in array Y from the corresponding element in X

```
Z = imsubtract(X,Y)
```

so the answer is: all of them.

Answer (score 0):

You might run into problems if you attempt to subtract a m x n x 3 (RGB) background from a m x n x 3 x nimage stack, as in this example:

```
stack= uint8(round(rand(10,10,3,4)*255)); % <- stack is  ( 10 x 10 x 3 ) x 4
bkrd = uint8(round(rand(10,10,3)*255));  % <- background is  ( 10 x 10 x 3 )

imsubtract(stack,bkrd)
```

output:

```
 ??? Function imlincomb expected its array input arguments (A1, A2, ...) to be the same size.

 Error in ==> imlincomb at 85
 Z = imlincombc(images, scalars, output_class);

 Error in ==> imsubtract at 47
     Z = imlincomb(1.0, X, -1.0, Y);
```

You can use `repmat` instead if your images are not too big (otherwise looping over individual images might be better):

```
stack_corr = imsubtract(stack,repmat(bkrd,[1,1,1,size(stack,4)]));

figure
subplot(121)
image(stack(:,:,:,3))

subplot(122)
image(stack_corr(:,:,:,3))
```